# TTURLNavigation: Is it efficient?

Tags: iphone, ios, three20

So I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around TTURLNavigation from the three20 framework.

Are the views being pushed onto a stack? I don't understand how one could just jump around an application without pushing and poping. I feel like if i just keep jumping to urls I am constantly pushing views onto my stack.

How exactly does TTURLNavigation accomplish this.